i want to clear dropdown after selecting items (multiple), controller is not found
i want to clear dropdown field after chosing it, i don't seem to find controller or similar.
i am using animated custom dropdown package https://pub.dev/packages/animated_custom_dropdown
Container(
                      height: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1),
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: CustomDropdown(
                        hideSelectedFieldWhenExpanded: true,
                        hintText: 'Category',
                        decoration: CustomDropdownDecoration(
                            hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                        items: categories,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      height: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1),
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Center(
                          child: CustomDropdown.multiSelect(
                        hintText: 'Sub Category',
                        items: subCategories,
                        decoration: CustomDropdownDecoration(
                            hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                        onListChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                      )),
                    ),

how can i clear selection after selecting multiple sub categories.

Hey there. I am the author of this package.
Controllers support is now available in the latest release 3.1.1. You can check!

Unfortunately, unable to find textController. But I saw that a property called initialItem is mentioned in the Custom Dropdown package documentation. I think it will be possible to change the value by calling setState after submitting the form. I don't sure try this.
you can modify your CustomDropdown widget like this:
bool isFormSubmit = false; // create variable 
void formSubmit(){  //when form submitted
  setState(() { isFormSubmit=true; });
}

    CustomDropdown(
        hideSelectedFieldWhenExpanded: true,
        hintText: 'Category',
        decoration: CustomDropdownDecoration(
        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        color: Colors.black,
         )),
        items: categories,
        initialItem:isFormSubmit? null:categories[0] , // add this 
        onChanged: (value) {
           print(value);
        },
       ),
     ),


hey, you tied this?

Hey there. I am the author of this package. Controllers support is now available in the latest release 3.1.1. You can check!
